# Confirmation dialog before leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 forms on page. And I want to add confirm for users if they change their profile information and wish to leave the page without saving information. I use jQuery.
I want to show the modal window with two buttons - leave the page and stay on the page

Also when the user clicks on the save button - the page reloads. But I don't need to show confirmation if user clicks on save button. Only if user wants to leave the page without saving profile info

first form

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input autocomplete="off" type="text" required="" class="form-control" value="candidate77" name="cand_name" placeholder="Write Full Name">
   <input class="file-caption-name" placeholder="Select file">
   <select class="select-generat form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="cand_salary_type" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option value="34" selected="selected">Monthly</option>
      <option value="35">Weekly</option>
      <option value="36">Hourly</option>
      <option value="37">Yearly</option>
   </select>
   <textarea name="cand_intro" data-parsley-error-message="Feild is required" class="form-control rich_textarea" cols="30" rows="10" data-origin="textarea">1231</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Information" class="btn n-btn-flat cand_person_save">
</div>
```

second form

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
           <div id="dropzone" class="dropzone dz-clickable">
              <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>undefined</span></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Video url (only youtube)</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Put youtube video link" value="" name="cand_video" class="form-control">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <input type="submit" value="Save Portfolio" class="btn n-btn-flat">
</div>
```

modal form

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Are you sure you want to leave this page?</h2>
        <p>please save updates</p>
    </div>
    <a href="/home">Leave page</a>
    <a href="/update-info">Stay on page</a>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var is_changed = 0;
    $(".form-control").on("input", function(){
        is_changed = 1;
    });
    //textarea
    $('rich_textarea').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        is_changed = 1;
    });
    //dropzone
    $(".dropzone").on('click', function(){
        is_changed = 1;
    });
    
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
      if (is_changed == 1) {
          $('#openModal').show();
      }
  } 
});
```

Comment: You can not show your own arbitrary modal when using `beforeunload`, the browser will provide its own confirmation dialog.

Comment: _"But I don't need to show confirmation if user clicks on save button."_ - then remove your beforeunload handler again, the moment the save button gets clicked.

Comment: can I use this code for beforeunload ? window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        if (formmodified == 1) {
            return "New information not saved. Do you wish to leave the page?";
        }
    }

Comment: Also how to remove beforeunload handler for button? Using onclick event? $('.btn ').click(function () {
  $(window).off('beforeunload');
}

Comment: Not sure if `.off()` works, when you added the handler via `window.onbeforeunload = ...`. But `window.onbeforeunload = null` should do to completely remove it.